# laravel/passport Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I use laravel/passport for my api authentication.
My problem is that, when I want to register via Postman as a new User on my localhost,everything works good, but the same code on live server returns me something like below:

> Trying to get property of non-object
>   "exception": "ErrorException",
>       "file": "/vendor/laravel/passport/src/ClientRepository.php",
>       "line": 89,

My user register code is below:

```
  $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
    ]);



    $success['name'] =  $user->name;
    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('Test')->accessToken;
    return response()->json(['success' => $success], 200);
```

Comment: please post your route.

Comment: Route::post('/register', 'Api\AuthController@register') this is my route, but it works fine on my localhost

Comment: which laraevl version ??

Comment: Laravel version is 5.5 and passport version is ~4.0

Comment: Did you run this command on your live server `php artisan passport:keys`? This command generates the encryption keys Passport needs in order to generate access token.

Answer (score 5):

I have same issue. Following commands solved my problem.

1. Run the migration

```sh
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

2. Install passport again

```sh
// Re-install passport
php artisan passport:install

// Or, only create personal access token
php artisan passport:client --personal
```

Comment: my application on shared host I have no ssh connection when I try to run this command with my route I got this error: `The command "passport install" does not exist.`

Comment: `php artisan passport:install`

Comment: Thanks @abkrim. I've edited the answer. Hope it helps.